# How do you call methods on a Collection entity in an #each

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am very, very new to Meteor.  I am using Iron Router to create a fairly simply Blog site.  What I'd like to do is have functions added to my Blogs collection entities that allows me to return a "preview" of a given post.  Using the 3rd answer to [this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007231/whats-the-best-way-to-attach-behavior-to-a-meteor-collection), I added something like this:

```
Blogs = new Meteor.Collection('blogs', {
    transform: function(entry) {
        // Add any custom methods to the Blog
        entry.getBodyMinimal = function(length) {
            if (length == null) {
                length = 100;
            };
            return this.body.substr(1,length);
        };
        return entry;
    }
});
```

However, I have no clue how to call it in the template as part of my `{{#each blogsList}}` loop. I tried `{{{ this.getBodyMinimal(10) }}}` and `{{{.getBodyMinimal(10) }}}` and neither worked.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass args by separating them with spaces.

`{{{ getBodyMinimal 10 }}}`

[Spacebars documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/spacebars#helper-arguments)